# How to judge which compliance I have to ensure in order to sell my circuit board in India?

Tags: emc, legal

I have a made a similar board like the Arduino Uno, but little bit higher-end. I want to sell it in India.

How do I know which certification I need to have for a product line like this (general electronic boards?)  BIS has only a specific set of products listed. What are the regulatory things I need to check before selling it?

Comment: Contact your local certification lab.

Comment: Look at a simmilar product already being sold and the certs it has.

Comment: You need to also define what your product is exactly for us to answer this question? Does it have radiators? Does it plug into the wall?

Comment: @VoltageSpike : No it is just like Uno board. we can power using standard adapter. it is a microcontroller development board. No antennas and all. I can design for EMC standards. but for me major problem is to know which standards to follow.

Comment: How fast is the processor, clocks can become radiators